# How do I get rid of the different horizontal distances

Tags: formatting, header-footer

between page boarder and Header respectively normal text?

```
 \documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside]{book}
    \usepackage{titlesec} 
    \titleformat{\chapter}[hang] 
    {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{ \thechapter}{1cm}{} 

    \begin{document}
    \chapter{ABC}
    asdasd
    \end{document}
```

I would like that the text starts exactly beyond the header and not some mm moved to the left. 
In the best case the header would move the appropriate length to the left.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Could you be more explicit? Your problem isn't very clear to me.

Comment: Note: a header is located above the text area (in that little box shown by showframe).  \chapter produces a title (or heading) and changes the header as well, hence the confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution using `\titlespacing*`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, oneside]{book}
\usepackage[noindentafter]{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]
{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{ \thechapter}{1cm}{}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{-0.55em}{*10}{*7.5}
\usepackage{showframe} 
\renewcommand{\ShowFrameLinethickness}{0.3pt}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{chapter}{5}

\chapter{ABC}

Some text beginning with no indentation. Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah. 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

There is a spurious space before `thechapter` in your code:

[image]

Simple remove the red marked space (between oppening brace and `\thechapter` command):

```latex
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang] 
  {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\thechapter}{1cm}{}
```

Exampleː

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{showframe}% only to show the page layout
\usepackage{titlesec} 
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang] 
  {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\thechapter}{1cm}{}

\begin{document}
\chapter{ABC}
asdasd
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to the indentation of paragraphs, try this one:

```
\noindent
```

Read more at https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Paragraph_Formatting#Paragraph_indent

Comment: The header is indented and i would like to move it a little bit to the left.